# Most efficient way to update a column where Id exists in another table

Tags: postgresql

I have several tables which correspond to *fiscal_years* (2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, etc). Each of these tables contain a *record_id* and an *owner_id* - with the *record_id* being unique within a given year. Each of the *fiscal_year* tables contain 6-8 million rows, and the *owners* table contains 1 million rows. Each of these *fiscal_year* tables contain a *process_date* field meant to represent the date when the *owner_id* was added/found/moved.

I have created a dynamic sql function that can retrieve the *owner_id*s unique among all of these tables and put them into an *owner* table - this part works fine and takes appx. 5 min to complete.

However, I am struggling to update the source table's (*fiscal_years*) *process_date* field if its *owner_id* exists in the *owner* table.

I have tried this:

```
update fiscal_year y
set process_date = now()
where exists (select owner_id from owners o where o.owner_id = y.owner_id)
and process_date is null;
```

But predictably, this query ran for 2 hours before I stopped it.

I also tried to use an etl tool to update the *fiscal_year* table using *owners.owner_id* as a key. But this method never finished either - presumably because there are many owner_ids that don't exist in each *fiscal_year* table.

How can I update the *fiscal_years* table when the *owner_id* is present in the *owners* table?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: Thank you for your link, @mustaccio, I will edit my question appropriately.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! Could you please provide your table structures - fiscal_year and owners (as text and with indexes).

Answer (score 1):

use of exists like that will cause repeated querying of owners for each row in fiscal_year

this will be better:

```
 update fiscal_year y
 set process_date = now()
 where y.owner_id in (select owner_id from owners)
 and process_date is null;
```

Here owners will be scanned once and the results remembered and re-used to verify each row.

Comment: I can't say if this approach or the join proposed by JD will perform best, try both. most efficient probaby depends on what your data looks likel

Answer (score 0):

I believe by doing an `EXISTS` on a subquery you may be using a sub-optimal way to accomplish this. Why not emulate an `INNER JOIN` directly like so:

```
update fiscal_year y
set y.process_date = now()
from owners o
where y.owner_id = o.owner_id
and y.process_date is null;
```

Having an index on `(owner_id, process_date)` for the `fiscal_year` table should help ensure the most optimal operations occur in this case too.

Your tables aren't *big* by any means, this process should be able to execute in minutes if not seconds, as long as everything is architected properly. I'd be curious what the above yields you (with the recommended index).